# Reading a Global Variable from a Thread and Writing to that Variable from another Thread

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

My program has 2 threads and a int global variable. One thread is reading from that variable and other thread is writing to that variable. Should I use mutex lock in this situation.

These functions are executing from 2 threads simultaneously and repetitively in my program.

```
void thread1()
{
    if ( condition1 )
        iVariable = 1;
    else if ( condition2 )
        iVariable = 2;
}

void thread2()
{
    if ( iVariable == 1)
        //do something
    else if ( iVarable == 2 )
        //do another thing

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use any synchronization then it is entirely unpredictable when the 2nd thread sees the updated value.  This ranges somewhere between a handful of nanoseconds and **never**.  With the *never* outcome being particularly troublesome of course, it can happen on a x86 processor when you don't declare the variable *volatile* and you run the Release build of your program.  It can take a long time on processors with a weak memory model, like ARM cores.  The only thing you don't have to worry about is seeing a partially updated value, *int* updates are atomic.

That's about all that can be said about the posted code.  Fine-grained locking rarely works well.

Comment: Say, thread1() is going to assign 1 to iVariable ( say, old value of iVariable is 0 ) Simultaneously thread2() function evaluates the (iVariable == 1) expression inside if condition. I know that the boolean returned by the (iVariable == 1) expression is unpredictable. But I want to get to know whether after executing the thread1() function, the value of iVariable1 is 1 or some other garbage value.

Comment: That's the "only thing you don't have to worry about" I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Then there is nothing to worry about. And no point of having mutex locks as no garbage values will be assigned to iVariable.

Comment: You don't seem to take the **never** clause in my answer very seriously.  This does inevitably have to be learned the hard way.

Comment: I didn't get it. What you mean by "never" is that it will not never be updated  although it should be. Am I correct?

Comment: No, it will be updated but the thread **never** sees the updated value, it keeps reading the old value.  You may think that's bizarre but it actually is possible.

Comment: If the both thread read that variable and no one is updating its value, should I use a mutex lock?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should (under most circumstances).  Mutexes will ensure that the data you are protecting will be correctly visible from multiple contending CPUs.  Unless you have a performance problem, you should use a mutex.  If performance is an issue, look into lock free data structures.

Comment: Without a mutex around iVariable, it is quite possible that not all CPUs in a multi core/CPU system will see the updates when you think it should.  Some of these memory visibility race conditions can be highly machine dependent.  So, use a mutex, spin lock or atomic variable.